# Accessing array elements from char*

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm new to c++ and am still struggling with the whole pointer thing.

Let's say I have a function that returns a char* pointing to the start of an array of characters / a string.

```
char* read() {

char data[] = "this for example";
return *data;
}
```

then later I want to access this data, but I don't think I can do something like this:

```
char* data = read();
if(data[3] == 's')
    return true;
```

what is the right way to use the data returned by `read()` in this example?

Comment: There is no right way, because you are returning a pointer to a local array. De-referencing it outside of the function is undefined behaviour.

Comment: What is "s"? In the line `if(data[3] == s)`

Comment: If you are starting coding C++ now, learn it *now* not as it was years ago. Look at shared_ptr, unique_ptr, etc.

Comment: s was meant to be 's'

Comment: Read a beginner C++ tutorial. I simply cannot *possibly* believe that the usage of the `*` dereference operator was not explained to any of them. `return *data` returns the first character of the array, not a pointer to it. This shouldn't even have compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is better to use standard class `std::string`

```
std::string read() 
{
   char data[] = "this for example";
   return data;
}
//...
std::string data = read();
if( data[3] == s )
    return true;
```

As for your code snippet then if to rewrite it without errors it would have undefined behaviour because you return a pointer to a local array that will be destroyed after exiting the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return pointer to an *automatic* variable. It invokes **undefined behavior**. Allocate `data` dynamically.

```
char *data = new char[20];
```

Do not forget to delete the allocated memory when you are done by using

```
delete[] data;
```

Better to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: You're recommending `new[]` and `delete[]`? Use `std::vector` or `unique_ptr<[]>`

Comment: better, `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `read()` function, `return *data;` returns a `char` *not* a `char*`. Also stack memory is not supposed to be accessed after your function returns. Make it static. It should be:

```
char* read()
{
    static char data[] = "this for example";
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Instead of making an explicit static array, why not just return the string literal itself? This is overly, unnecessarily complex, `return "this for example";` would do the same thing.

Comment: @user3477950 It wouldn't be the same, because this one allows you to modify the string.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh yes, forgot that. In first place, I wouldn't assume that one should modify a char array returned from a function. It doesn't seem terribly well practice.